# How to make rails validate trim before checking for length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `user.rb` model I have the following:

```
validates :fname, :length => { :minimum => 1, :maximum => 100 }, :unless => Proc.new { |user|  user.new_record? || !user.password_confirmation.nil? }
```

The problem is users can submit fname as `"    "` which is all whitespace and this tricks the validation. How can I make validates trim before looking for the length?

Answer (score 3):

you can add a before_validation callback to trim fname

```
before_validation :trim_fname

def trim_fname
  self.fname.strip!
end
```

Comment: Thanks but that seems crazy to have to do this for all fields/models. Is there not built in magic rails way to do this?

Comment: i'm not sure if there is a way to do it for all models, but for a single model, you can iterate through each attribute and call strip on it.

Comment: @AnApprentice - What kind of magic are you looking for? Look again at your original validation, it works exactly as written. The problem is that you have an additional condition that is taken into account. Sometimes you just have to write code to do what you want.

Comment: Can I add something to my unless that trims and checks the length?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try this gem: https://github.com/holli/auto_strip_attributes, that might be a quick fix for this.

Regards,